# Edits to comments should give a pop-in, just like it is with questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

When *another person's* comment is edited, in order to see an edit has been made you have to refresh. In case this idea has not been given here on Meta, why not make edits to comments give a pop-in, just like it is with questions and answers?

Comment: Um, what? I never need to click refresh when I edit a comment. Test. Yep. I don't need to press refresh for that.

Comment: Do you mean when someone else edits *their* comment you have to refresh to see it?

Comment: @James Indeed .

Comment: But edits to questions and answers don't appear instantly, there's a pop-in that tells you it's been edited but you still have to click or refresh to activate it.

Comment: @Catija Indeed, but you can instantly see an edit has been made. This should be the case with comments too.

Comment: Then you should change your question to reflect the **actual** behavior and to explain what you want more completely.

Answer (score 4):

Comments are not important, and are referred to as "2nd (and 3rd) class citizens". We don't have comment history or revisions, and once deleted they are gone without a trace, etc.

Also, there are a great deal of comments, and often new ones flying in quite quickly on a question, so the site resource cost would be quite high with little return to refresh them all (or notify when they have been edited).

Questions and answers don't auto-refresh anyway, you are notified there is an edit, and you click to refresh. But questions and answers have this functionality as they are essential parts of the site.

Doing this with comments would be *insane*.

Comment: It's interesting how I just expected to see *comments are second-class citizens* in the answer while scrolling down. The very sentence has answered a lot of feature requests. :)

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani The sentence has answered a lot of feature requests *specifically* about comments :) Usually wanting to make comments something they are not. While comments are very useful, they are not that important, and having too much functionality in comments is not worthwhile.